# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'vertices'

Tags: c++, directx

I would usually search for this error. But in VS C++ Express, this error comes up for just about every mistake you do.  Any how I recieve this error below

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'vertices'
```

everytime I add the following code at the top of my document

```
// Create vertex buffer
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{
    D3DXVECTOR3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
    D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    D3DXVECTOR3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
};
```

below is the code in it's entirety. Cant figure out whats wrong. thanks

[EDIT]

```
// include the basic windows header file
#include "D3Dapp.h"


class MyGame: public D3Dapp
{
    public:
        bool Init3d();
};
MyGame game;

struct SimpleVertex
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 Pos;  // Position
};


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
     game.InitWindow(hInstance , nCmdShow);
     return game.Run();
}


bool MyGame::Init3d()
{
    D3Dapp::Init3d();
    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        D3DXVECTOR3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    }

    return true;
}
```

new error

```
1>c:\users\numerical25\desktop\intro todirectx\msdntutorials\tutorial0\tutorial\tutorial\main.cpp(14) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Pos'
```

Comment: Is the `SimpleVertex` class defined in `D3Dapp.h`?

Comment: No it isn't, The first appearance of SimpleVertex is where you see it now.

Comment: I edited the code. See the top

Comment: Don't adapt the `T[] t` syntax given by stakx - it is wrong and should be `T t[]`.

Comment: ok, I changed it back. Updated the code

Comment: You forgot `;` at the end of array declaration and also you have unneded `,` after last array element.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> ```
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'vertices'
> ```

Usually this error occurs when what's before the identifier isn't known to the compiler. In your case that means the compiler hasn't seen `SimpleVertex` yet.

Comment: I edited the code. See the original post

Comment: @numerical25: The same answer applies. It now complains about a `;` missing before `Pos`. So I would presume it doesn't know `D3DXVECTOR3`. Was that so hard?

Comment: I believe it. But at the same time I would suspect an error stating that undeclared or undefined varible has been made. Something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely see a missing semicolon `;` toward the end of `main` right before `return true;`.

Comment: Yea, I got that error after I corrected the first one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extra comma is added at the end of last member of the structure. I think this was the mistake.

```
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{
    D3DXVECTOR3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
    D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    D3DXVECTOR3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f )**,**
}
```